# Difficulty Expressing Function For Plotting

Tags: pgfplots

I'm attempting to use pgfplots to plot a graph with the following code

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[
axis lines = left,
xlabel = $n$,
ylabel = {$p_{n}$},
]
\pgfmathsetmacro{\P}{520000}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\m}{3162.28}
\pgfmathsetmacro{\r}{1.0045}


\addplot [
domain=1:300, 
samples=300, 
color=red,
]
{100 - 100*((\r - 1)*(\P\r^(\x - 1)-\m*((\r^\x - 1)/(\r - 1)))/\m};
\addlegendentry{$p$}

\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Here is the function I would like to plot:[image]

And here is the plot I'm currently getting:
[image]

I suspect the problem is with the parsing of my function but I'm not sure. I've tested a few values of the function with a calculator and the formula I have seems correct, or at the very least to produce values that look nothing like the plot. Any input/comments would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

pgf doesn't have implicit multiplication.  This means that something like `2\x` will give an error.  Even worse, `\P\r` is expanding to `5200001.0045`, so that your `$Pr^{n-1}$` is becoming `$(10P+r)^{n-1}$`, resulting in a humongous number to plot. Instead, you want to write `\P*\r^(\x-1)`.

For a similar reason, you would also want `(\r)^\x` if you had negative `\r`.  Otherwise, `-2^\x` would be interpreted as `-(2^\x)`.  But that doesn't seem to be a problem here.